# Array.sort() method change my object before it called, mutability issue?

Tags: javascript

I think there is a notion that I do not understand well, namely the notion of mutability.

Here is my code:

```
console.log(inputs); // Already sorted (?!)
// sort the array
inputs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
});
```

Only thing is, my console.log shows me the array inputs already sorted, while the .sort() method only applies afterwards.

I think it's a mutability problem, I just don't quite understand the scope of it. Why my console.log print the array already sorted ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your inputs? You can try it with 2 different datasets and see console.

Comment: This is because console will render object key/values (like array values) asynchronously.